# Why does QSpatialite show the same table twice?

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

I have created a point table in QSpatialite, by creating a new table first and then adding a geometry column, as described [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html).

The table shows up twice in QSpatialite, which surprised me a bit:

[image]

I didn't really care about that (maybe having two different views of the table is appropriate) and thought that they would be linked somehow. Then I added two columns to the first item named 'Gebaeude_P' (the one labeled with a table-like looking icon). In QSpatialite I can see those two extra columns in both tables, but in QGIS I can see them only in the attribute table for the first one.

From the log message panel:

```
2016-05-02T16:05:12 1   Error executing query: SELECT styleQML FROM layer_styles WHERE f_table_catalog='path_to_db.sqlite' AND f_table_schema='' AND f_table_name='Gebaeude_P' AND f_geometry_column='Geometry' ORDER BY CASE WHEN useAsDefault THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,update_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

What happened here? I'm also having difficulties creating tables and table views with QSpatialite. Most of the time, the data simply isn't visible in QGIS.